# JS Prototype: Avoiding an event handler being bound several times to the same object

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, dom-events

So with the new ajax things we have to reinitialize our Javascript event handlers every time an ajax call is made, since an ajax call can result in pretty heavy redrawing of the whole page resulting in uninitialized objects.

Have a look at this jsfiddle:
[Javascript eventhandler added multiple times to the same object](http://jsfiddle.net/SBB9g/23/)

This is what I have and it seems to work, but since it is going  to be used with everything we have: I wanna make sure that it is the right solution.
E.g. the global defined variable

```
    MyCompany.field.bindedOnfocusSelector = MyCompany.field._focusEventHandler.bindAsEventListener(MyCompany.field);
```

just feels wrong. And it lacks the possibility to hand more function arguments.

As another poster suggested the prototype `$(smth).on(event)` I have problems to get it working - I remember problems crossbrowser wise (e.g. on IE 8 things didn't work which worked in Firefox) and even in this simpler example [jsFiddle problem with on('focus')](http://jsfiddle.net/SBB9g/25/):

Answer (score 2):

How about you register an ajax responder, and add the methods after a request has completed

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
    onComplete: function(transport) {
        MyCompany.field._initTextInputFields();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, taking into consideration your comment, how about observing the whole page i.e. `body` and determining if a input event occurred, ex:

```
 $("#body").on("focus", "input[type=text]:not([readonly])", function(event, element) {
    // ....
 });
```

I think this will help you as you only add one observer, and never need to remove it, all your logic can be contained.

PS: note that `Event.on` is only available in prototype 1.7

**UPDATE**

ok, what if you just check the click, keyboard won't work now though but i think this is a viable solution

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBB9g/30/)

Comment: the problem with this approach is, that I get a list of IDs of sections, regions etc which themselves contain a number of input fields. I do not know which input fields existed before the call. So basically I would end up adding the handlers a multiple times. Maintaining lists and removing observers before adding seems more difficult than just adding them again for all fields. Performance ? I don't know to be honest, maybe I have to take that into consideration as well for big pages with a lot of fields.

Comment: i updated my question, it just does not work (in this setup for focus at least)